2D Stokeslet: a reference?
Consider the Stokes equation
$$ \begin{cases}\Delta u = \nabla p - F \\ \operatorname{div}(u)=0 \end{cases} \text{ in } \mathbb{R}^2,$$
with $u$ a velocity field, $p$ a pressure and $F$ a point force in the origin, directed along the $y$ axis. The velocity $u$ solving the Stokes equation in this case is called stokeslet, and in the 3D case it's given by a well-known formula, that is
$$ u(r) = J(r) \cdot F, \text{ with } J(r)= \frac{1}{8\pi} \left( \frac{Id}{|r|} + \frac{rr}{|r|^3}\right) .$$
Now, I would like to see both a derivation of this formula in the 3D case AND in the 2D case, which I have been unable to find anywhere.
